# Biblatex produces incomplete .bcf with biber backend

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, documentclass-writing

I am developing a latex documentclass and am having a rather strange problem with `biblatex` and the `biber` backend. As described [here](https://github.com/cgogolin/quantum-journal/issues/22), when I run `pdflatex` and then `biber` on this `minimal.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{quantumarticle}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{minimal.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Foo2035}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with this `minimal.bib`

```
@article{Foo2035,
  author = {Foo, Bar},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2010},
  title = {Title},
  doi = {doi},
}
```

Biber produces the following error (logged to `minimal.blg`):

```
[0] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.6
[0] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'minimal.blg'
[33] biber:302> INFO - === Tue Dec 13, 2016, 16:21:37
[46] Utils.pm:180> ERROR - minimal.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted minimal.bbl
[46] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Indeed, inspecting `minimal.bcf` reveals that `biblatex` did not close the  `<bcf:section>` tag in `minimal.bcf` and did not include a `<bcf:sortlist>`. The file ends with

```
  [...]
  <bcf:section number="0">
    <bcf:citekey order="1">Foo2035</bcf:citekey>
```

Simply adding the lines

```
  </bcf:section>
</bcf:controlfile>
```

and then running `biber` again makes the error go away and a subsequent `pdflatex` run produces the expected output.

Replacing `quantumarticle` with the standard `article` class, on which my class is based, resolves the problem.

Of course I do not expect you to go through my whole documentclass to find the mistake, but I don't even know where to start looking for the problem.

What could possibly make `biblatex` write an incomplete `.bcf` file without throwing any error?

Comment: The ltxgrid package seems to be part of the problem.

Comment: I know you say 'I do not expect you to go through my whole documentclass', but that the only obvious way to find the issue: bisection led me (and @UlrikeFischer) to `ltxgrid` ...

Comment: Is there a systematic automatizable way of doing bisection? I can hardly believe that you found the source of this error by commenting out different parts of the cls file and compiling? I though that by doing this one would break so many other things that it would be a hopeless endeavor.

Comment: @cgogolin  Used `\endinput` but the idea is the same: avoid anything where the lines obviously go together, target in the first instance package loading, _etc._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is `ltxgrid`, or rather the `ltxutil` package it loads: you can see this with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ltxgrid}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{minimal.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Foo2035}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where the order of packages *is* important.

Tracing carefully, you find that `ltxutil` (which doesn't like being loaded without `ltxgrid`) does

```
\def\enddocument{%
 \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
 \@enddocumenthook
 \@checkend{document}%
 \clear@document
 \check@aux
 \deadcycles\z@
 \@@end
}%
```

*i.e.* an arbitrary redefinition of the macro. If you revert this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\savedenddocument\enddocument
\usepackage{ltxgrid}
\let\enddocument\savedenddocument
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{minimal.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Foo2035}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the issue goes away (you then get some odd lines in the terminal).

The problem is that both `etoolbox` and `ltxutil` are trying to set up various hooks. With `etoolbox`, code is added by patching with a fallback if it fails, so there is no error if `etoolbox` is loaded first. On the other hand, as `ltxutil` simply zaps `\enddocument`, anything installed by `etoolbox` is lost.

All of this bites `biblatex` as it puts material into hooks provided by `etoolbox`, so when the hook insertion is lost the material is effectively too.

---

You can get back the writing from `biblatex` by adding

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\enddocument
  {\deadcycles}
  {\let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone    
   \@afterenddocumenthook
   \deadcycles}
  {}
  {\AtEndDocument{%
     \let\etb@@end\@@end
     \def\@@end{%
       \let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
       \@afterenddocumenthook
       \etb@@end}}}
\makeatother
```

(which is what `etoolbox` does in the first place) after loading `ltxgrid`: this re-introduces the hook used by `biblatex`. You will find some odd lines in your terminal output, related to the fact that the normal mechanisms for writing `lot`, `lof`, *etc.* have been altered by `ltxgrid`. (It's all about altering how things go onto the main vertical list, so that's not surprising: see `xgalley` for the team approach in this area, which is *much more* non-compatible with any code that doesn't know about it!)

Comment: I will see what can be done from the `etoolbox` end about this: tricky as it's only going to show up if `ltxutil` is loaded after `etoolbox`.

Comment: WOW! I read your answer in utter amazement. Many, many thanks!

Comment: @JosephWright Where to add this snippet? At the top of the preamble?

Comment: Also, this does not seem to be just a problem with ltxgrid/ltxutil - I am not loading that package and still getting the error. Although it has started happening just a few days ago. Trying to identify the changes to my system that could have impacted this.

Comment: @SACHINGARG The same issue could arise from a different package but without an example its hard to say. Please post a separate question linking to this one.